# Sending an email with ASP.net from a gmail email

Tags: asp.net, email, gmail

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sending email in .NET through Gmail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32260/sending-email-in-net-through-gmail)

Say I want to send an email from an account named `"agoogleaccount@gmail.com"` to the email `"billy@live.com"`.  I'm sending it from a gmail account.  Say the password for the gmail account is `letmein`.  What would be the snippet to send the email?  I've been scouring the internet for an hour now to no avail.  Nothing I find works (for me).

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this: http://geekswithblogs.net/TakeNote/archive/2007/07/16/113974.aspx